# How can I downgrade Target Framework from .NET 5.0 to .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc, .net-5

I am recently building a Desktop Application using .net 5.0 . Everything was okay until I tried using rdlc report viewer using nuget package `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms 150.1484.0`, which somehow is not supported and shows the error [image: Error is as shown here]
And again I tried a new sample project for report with to .NET Framework 4.7.2 and it's working fine. How can I resolve this issue? Is it possible to change my target framework to .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Comment: if you don't use any feature of the .net 5, then you can just copy all your code to the new project that uses .net 4.7

Comment: It's a real shame that MS decided not to develop a .NET 5+ version of the report viewer components.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms (use for .Net Framework)

ReportViewerCore.WinForms (use for .Net Core/.Net, this is still a work in-progress and unofficial). You can review it on there github [ReportViewer Core](https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore) repository.

But if you are really have the capability to fallback to .Net Framework much better so that you can use the official Report Viewer.